# How to write pytests for MetaFlow DAGs?

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, netflix-metaflow

What is the correct way to write unit tests for individual MetaFlow steps? And, how do you test full DAGs using fixtures in place of real datasets? How can I ensure that these tests' artifacts don't pollute the artifact store?